# VSCode: search for a consecutive string in go-to symbol

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm searching for the function named "init"; along with init, I also get things like:

"funct**i**o**n** g = compute_grad**i**en**t**()"

where the substring characters aren't consecutive. Most of the time, it makes the whole search useless (faster to use a simple string search).

How do I fix that?

By the way, is this a bug? If not, what's the idea of such a search? I could understand looking for separate (by space) words; I don't get a search by separate letters.

Comment: Doesn't do that on my machine... Btw, go-to symbol is `in editor` simply quick open starting with `@` and in `project / workspace` starting with `#`. Does the same happen when you search like that?

Comment: If you are talking about the quickPanel search for symbols?  If so, what you are seeing are fuzzy search results therein.  I thought there was a setting to make it more or less fuzzy/greedy but I can't find it now.

Comment: Okay, so it's called a fuzzy search. I googled it, and it seems like an on going issue--a feature by design. (@n-smits, yes.)